# How to switch clients to second server during transmission when server disconnect

Tags: java, sockets, rmi

I am creating a client/server chat, and trying to create a redundant server.

When the primary server fails, clients switch to the second server.

In the client side I have a connection method where I initiate a socket, aninput stream and an output stream. I want to make a Remote object call using RMI repeatedly and every time this object is not reachable there will be an exception thrown.

I am struggling how to implement this trick and make it work. The thing is not only when a client connects first to check the remote object, but also when the socket is connected and there is data going between through the streams the object should be checked.

If you have any clue please do not hesitate. Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem?

Comment: @AnubianNoob how to use RMI to detect that server is down, accordingly switching user to second server. Thank you

Comment: you need some "ping" routine.

Comment: @MingtaoZhang can you help me to write ping routine during reading and writing to the socket. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the target of a remote method call is down, you will get a RemoteException of some kind:

- a ConnectException if there wasn't already a pooled connection to reuse, or
- a MarshallException or UnmarshallException, depending on at what phase the outage was detected.

At that point you would need to look up the other registry and retry with the other stub so obtained.

You don't need sockets for any of this.